# Run concurrent call from one client MVC long call

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

The problem is when client run long call execution can not browse other pages until this execution call is finished.

The question is how to allow user to concurrent long execution in MVC.

This process happen in admin area and I want admin can run multiple of this calls.

I show all call status by signalR and progress but the website is under Cloudflare and cloudflare do not accept call more than 100sec and return me `524` timeout error I want to prevent this error also

thank you

Comment: It's hard to get what you really want. Can you show some code of this long running call?

Comment: sounds like maybe you want your user to set a flag (maybe in a database) which will trigger a background process (in a separate thread, or even a separate executable such as a windows service)

Answer (score 0):

MVC only run one process and wait until process finished.

I disabled session manager in controllers for my tasks

by adding this

```
    [SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]
```